# Creating category from flat file csv and save in loop

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-tree

I have csv flat file with the items and with the category and subcategories attached to this item. Using this file i have to create a categories tree. I have this piece of code:

```
there is a loop here and some code to get data from file line by line{        
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
           $category->setName($level);
           $category->setUrlKey(strtolower($level));
           $category->setIsActive(1);
           $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
           $category->setIsAnchor(1);
           $category->setStoreId(1);
           $category->setPath($parent_path);
           $category->save();
}
```

and generally it works fine but because of `save()` method in loop it takes ages... how could I optimize it? I tried to move `save()` outside the loop but it doesn't work also `saveAttribute()` method doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no other build in way for categories.
and calling `saveAttribute` does not work because the category does not exist yet.
You can try to create something similar to the product import that bypasses the `save` method and writes directly in the tables, but I have no idea on how you can start on that.